# Get Week Before Last

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to pull data which will excluded the previous 2 weeks and include the 2 weeks beofre that.

so for example if today is the 31st of the month i want to exclude all data between the 15th and 31st and want to see only the 1st to the 15th

```
AND E.EventCreatedDateD between DATEADD(day,-14,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,-31,GETDATE())
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your statement?

Comment: The issue is that i get zero results from this statement. any ideas or another way to do this. maybe using weeks. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0 values from your statement because the dates are backwards.  Put the earlier date first:

```
AND E.EventCreatedDateD between DATEADD(day, -31, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE())
```

The order of the expressions for the between is important.  The lower value always needs to be first and the higher value second.

Comment: Thank you very much sir thats what i was missing!

Comment: @user2040295 . . . You can tell this is a subtle problem that can trip up a lot of people.  Many people read the question (as did I initially) missing the obvious.